# working holiday and tourist visas in schengen

Tags: schengen, netherlands, tourist-visas, working-holiday

I am an Australian and arrived in the Schengen end of April 2015. I travelled as a tourist around the schengen for 90 days and within the 90 days obtained a Working Holiday Visa in Netherlands. My working holiday visa in Netherlands will expire the beginning of July 2016. My question is, can I travel within the schengen for another 90 days as a tourist ? If so, do I need to somehow reset my stay here by re-entering the schengen as a tourist? I.e. travel to the UK at the end of my visa and re-enter ?